# CSS-анимация не работает для svg в <img>

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Я пытаюсь анимировать SVG в теге `image / object`, но анимация не работает.

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.rotate-45 {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rotate {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.rotate-back {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.left {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(calc(90deg + 45deg));
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-30px, -30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g transform="translate(500,500)">
      <rect class="rotate-45 rotate-back" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
      <rect class="rotate-45 rotate" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none" />
      <g transform="translate(-50,0) rotate(-45)">
        <polyline class="left" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(50,0) rotate(135)">
        <polyline class="right" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
      </g>
      <text y="-140" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-size="3em" font-family="sans-serif">loading data...</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Как анимировать `SVG` внутри тега изображения вместе с `CSS`.

Вот `plunker` для этого кода - https://plnkr.co/edit/TdfR7cpVaQArtcUs0Hro?p=preview

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46050871/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вы не можете анимировать внутренние элементы `<img>` снаружи. Даже если это SVG. Для этого есть две причины:

1. CSS не применяется к границам документа и
2. Изображения, на которые ссылается через `<img>`, должны быть автономными.

Анимация должна работать, если вы поместите CSS внутри внешнего SVG (как обычно, в элемент `<style>`).

Также обратите внимание, что вам нужно будет изменить способ преобразования - `transform-origin`.  Этот способ, которым он работает в `Chrome`, удобен, но он неверен в соответствии с текущей спецификацией. Он не будет работать в других браузерах, таких как Firefox.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style>
.rotate-45 {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rotate {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.rotate-back {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.left {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-30px, -30px);
  }
}
  </style>
  <g transform="translate(500,200)">
    <rect class="rotate-45 rotate-back" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/>
    <rect class="rotate-45 rotate" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none"/>
    <g transform="translate(-50,0) rotate(-45)"><polyline class="left" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/></g>
    <g transform="translate(50,0) rotate(135)"><polyline class="right" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/></g>
    <text y="-140" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-size="3em" font-family="sans-serif">loading data...</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46051272/7394871)

*Примечание:*

**Работает** во всех современных браузерах : `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Opera`, `Yandex`

**Не работает** анимация в `IE`, `Edge`, так как разработчики этих браузеров не хотят поддерживать [анимацию в полном объеме](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csstransitionsanimationsforsvgelements/)  и см. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=smil)

Comment: `SVG` нужно чаще использовать инлайново, а так в принципе и `object` подойдёт, но всё равно лучше первый вариант=)